# Solrcloud - remove a node

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a Solrcloud setup, which runs 3 ZKs and 3 Solrs (version 4.10.3). I would like to take out one of the Solr servers completely from this setup so that I only have 2 Solrs and 3 ZKs.

I've tried googling and the only results I can find are to remove replicas or collections but not to remove a node.

Any idea how I can remove a node in SolrCloud?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can first remove shards and replica. using below command

```
<SOLR_URL>/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETEREPLICA&collection=<Collection_name>&shard=<shard_name>&replica=<replica_node_naeme>
```

The shard name (shard) and replica node name (coreNodeName) values can be found in the core.properties file located under /solr/server/solr/.
For example:
http://localhost:9501/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETEREPLICA&collection=wblib&shard=shard1&replica=core_node1

Then you can delete the installation files for the removed Solr node.

Comment: I will give it a try and get back. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to remove all replicas on that one node using your script. Under live nodes, I still see the mode listed. If I stop tomcat then the node goes away but when I start tomcat on that server the node with the deleted replica still shows up. What else would I need to do to remove this node entirely from Solrcloud?

Comment: You can delete the physical folder of that node then restart the server. You can try to update zookeeper conf file to remove extra node.

Comment: Which config file specifically?

Comment: You can check below file.
./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh